# Netcore Elasticsearch (NEST) DefaultIndex is UriEncoded

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

Trying to get a basic Elasticsearch `Count` to work in my netcore API.

Following the documentation I believe this should work-

```
var node = new Uri(host);

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
settings.DefaultIndex("foo/bar");

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var x = await client.CountAsync<dynamic>();
return x.Count;
```

There is a problem with this, however. The DefaultIndex is encoding slashes (`/foo%2Fbar/object/_count`). I'm getting a `no_index_found_exception` exception.

It seems like an easy problem to fix, but I can't find the documentation for this.

How do I prevent uri encoding on my DefaultIndex?

Answer (score 1):

To specify multiple indices as the default index, separate them with a comma. NEST will URI encode the comma

```
var defaultIndex = "users,posts";

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
    .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
    .DefaultTypeName("doc");

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var searchResponse = client.Search<object>(s => s);
```

Will send a search request to

```
POST http://localhost:9200/users%2Cposts/doc/_search
```